# VB.net need help parsing a substring

Tags: vb.net

I have a value I am capturing from an Http Request

```
Dim someValue As String = Request.Params("search")
```

Here is the value of my string:

```
?MyId1=VALUE1&MyId2=VALUE2&MyBoolen=True
```

I am trying to capture `VALUE2`. I tried the below code, but haven't had any success.

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(someValue) Then
    Dim x = someValue.Substring(someValue.IndexOf("&"c) + 1)
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(someValue) Then
        Dim y = x.Substring(someValue.IndexOf("="c) + 1)
    End If
End If
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're overthinking this. The `Request` object will let you look up the `MyId2` value directly:

```
Dim MyId2 As String = Request.QueryString("MyId2")
```

It's also possible this is a nested query string, where what you actually have is something more like this:

```
/?search=%3FMyId1%3DVALUE1%26MyId2%3DVALUE2%26MyBoolen%3DTrue
```

This would give you the original string after the runtime URL Decodes the `search` element. In that case, you should look at [the `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring?view=net-7.0#system-web-httputility-parsequerystring(system-string)), rather than trying to do this yourself:

```
Dim search As String = Request.Params("search")
Dim searchValues As NameValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(search)
Dim MyId2 As String = searchValues("MyId2")
```

Which could even be written as a one-liner if we really wanted:

```
Dim MyId2 As String = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.Params("search"))("MyId2")
```

But if you *really* wanted to parse this by hand, one of the nice things about this is everything should be URL-encoded. This means you don't have worry about stray `&` or `=` characters as part of the data, and a simple `Split()` call should be safe:

```
Dim MyId2 As String = ""
Dim items = someValue.Substring(1).Split("&"c)
For Each item As String In Items 
    Dim parts = item.Split("="c)
    If parts(0) = "MyId2" Then
       MyId2 = parts(1)
       Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Or

```
Dim parts() As String = someValue.Substring(1).Split("&"c).
       Select(Function(s) s.Split("="c)).
       FirstOrDefault(Function(p) p(0) = "MyId2")

Dim MyId2 As String = If(parts IsNot Nothing, parts(1), "")
```